# Is there a file with hyphenation for long german words?

Tags: babel, hyphenation, german

Is there a file with lots of hyphenation? In my current project folder is no such file. I had to create it my own. I know that there are packages that could do the same but i find it very hard to install these and for specific words witch are not usually used. I think it would be very helpful when we could create a file as a community which can be used easily.
I have created a file where I add all of my long german complicated. You can add your words and also use the file for your document.

The [file](https://www.icloud.com/iclouddrive/0Zj_pXTpKSw1bYOcAziV84sWg#Silbentrennung).

Comment: What is the problem with `\usepackage[german]{babel} which supplies hyphenation rule for German text?

Comment: @PeterWilson `ngerman` please, otherwise you are approx. 20 years from current rules ;)

Comment: @TeXnician What is the difference between `german` and `ngerman`? The `babel` documentation mentions `austrian`, `german`, `germanb`, `ngerman` and `naustrian` but I didn't see (perhaps my fault)  any explanations of these.

Comment: @PeterWilson Well, in 1996 there was a major change in German orthography so instead of replacing the old rules (which some still prefer), babel was supplied with an additional `ngerman` implementing the new rules from 1996 on. I actually don't know what germanb is but austrian and naustrian have a similar history iirc.